# Use on premise LDAP for amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, aws-directory-service

I'm currently looking into amazon WorkMail but we have a on premise LDAP which is completely setup with integrations into multiple applications. What I would like to do is connect the workmail to this on premise LDAP as well.

At the moment I only see there being an `AD connector` I was wondering if it would also be able to connect this connector to the LDAP as well.

And if not is there another way to make this work? I can't seem to find anything about it really.

Comment: Maybe you could try the AD connector? If that doesn't work you could set up an LDAP server on a t2.nano/micro and sync / mirror them using application level features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

> You can integrate Amazon WorkMail with an existing directory such as an on-premises Microsoft Active Directory, AWS Managed Active Directory, or AWS Simple Active Directory.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/premises_directory.html